# Avoid handling all exceptions until they've reached a global handler

Tags: swift

If I call `hello.f`, the compiler forces me to handle *all* the thrown exceptions. I can swallow them using `try?` or add a `catch` all by not specifying the type of exception to catch and then re-throw. But, if I do the latter, I need to mark the calling function as throws and the process continues all the way up the stack.

Is it possible to ignore `f`'s exceptions such that they ultimately become un-handled exceptions that can be handled globally?

```
enum e : Error {
    case hello
    case world
}

class hello {
    func f() throws  {
        throw e.hello
    }
}
```

Comment: `rethrows` doesn't appear to be in the language guide.

Comment: that is beyond my scope, I did not wrote the language guide. :)

Comment: If you don't want to propagate the exception, don't rethrow it. Use `catch` and do nothing. Problem solved.

Comment: @rmaddy I do want to propagate the exception. I want to handle them globally.

Comment: @holex `rethrows` is applied to a function which takes a throwing function argument. I don't think that's applicable to my code.

Comment: Your title says "Avoid handling all exceptions". Please clarify what you mean. What do you mean by "handled globally"?

Comment: I think that you can't. It's by design. Swift is more strict on error handling.

Comment: @IanWarburton, yes, I revised the code I have quickly written in the comment, that was not the proper syntax, btw, but you can go for `func g() throws { try f() }` this, which is correct by now, you just forward the error in this case without handling it locally.

Comment: @holex You can't do that. The compiler says, "Errors thrown from here are not handled".

Comment: @IanWarburton, nope, compiler says nothing like that, that is a live code I just copied form my test app, based on your foundation.

Comment: What you want can be done using `rethrows` on each method up the chain. Then you can handle the actual exception at whichever level in the chain you want.

Comment: @holex aha... yes, it stops complaining when adding throws to the method.

Comment: @holex Seems to work. Please write it as an answer. The existing answer is incorrect.

Comment: @rmaddy `rethrows` is only applicable to functions that take a throwing function as an argument – marking each method up the chain as `throws` should work fine though.

Comment: @Hamish I realize that now. Using `throws` is what I should have stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to ignore f's exceptions such that they ultimately become un-handled exceptions that can be handled globally?

In a word, no. The entire point of the design of Swift's error handling is that you must *explicitly* acknowledge the possibility of error at every stage.

It sounds to me like you're thinking of how Objective-C deals with NSException, but Swift isn't like that (and Error is not like NSException).

Comment: Coming from C#... I think Anders Hejlsberg makes a good argument against this here... http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html.

Comment: Why can't `rethrows` be used? Then you simply pass the responsibility up to the previous caller in the chain. Isn't that what the OP wants?

Comment: Actually, `throws` is what I should have stated, not `rethrows`.

Comment: @rmaddy Absolutely, but that is not "ignoring". It is acknowledging, as I said. Of course it's possible that I didn't understand what Ian was after, but I thought he wanted to percolate up the chain _without_ saying `throw` / `try` at every stage, and I'm saying, rightly, that you can't do that.

Comment: Agreed that "ignoring" is not the right word (which I never used). "defer" would have been a better choice of words.

Comment: @rmaddy Sure. But I thought Ian really did mean "ignore". Because that is how e.g. the Responder Chain work, and how NSException handling works in Objective-C: the runtime just keeps walking up the call chain _looking_ for _someone_ to handle this thing. (But my point is, Swift error handling is not like that: _you must_ handle it somehow at every step of the walk up the call chain.

Answer (score 1):

based on your expectations, I have created this example:

```
enum PetError : Error {
    case pet
}

class Pet {
    func pet() throws  {
        throw PetError.pet
    }
}

class Cat {
    func cat() throws  {
        let pet = Pet()
        try pet.pet()
    }
}
class Tiger {
    func tiger() throws  {
        let cat = Cat()
        try cat.cat()
    }
}
```

---

then you can handle the `PetError` exceptions (=errors) on the highest level you need, while inside the chain the errors are just forwarded to the upper level.

```
let tiger = Tiger()
do {
    try tiger.tiger()
} catch PetError.pet {
    print("PetError.pet")
}
```

---

***NOTE:*** of course you may want to handle all exceptions (=errors) at the end of the day, but that is not part of this little example.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I'm after. The output is "hello\n". Thanks to holex in the comments of the question.

```
enum e : Error {
    case hello
    case world
}

class hello {
    func f() throws  {
        throw e.world
    }
}

class goodbye {
    func g() throws  {
        let h = hello()
        try h.f()
    }
}
class world {
    func w() throws  {
        let g = goodbye()
        try g.g()
    }
}

let w = world()
do {
try w.w()
}
catch e.world {
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: @holex I wanted to share more of my naming convention with the world. If you answer, I will give you the points.

Comment: @IanWarburton Speaking of naming conventions, type names should be `UpperCamelCase`, e.g `Hello`, `Goodbye`, `World` & `E`.

Comment: Still, I do think you are just proving that what I said is right. You _must_ explicitly show the compiler at every stage of the chain that you know an error can pass this way.

Comment: @IanWarburton, okay, I have posted an answer based on your code; I don't actually wanted extra credit, but I definitely against your naming conventions in Swift.

Comment: @holex Arguably its not a convention.

Comment: @matt That's a good point. holex's answer is really only a partial solution.

Comment: ok, so I think @matt gives the correct answer after all. And as Anders Hejlsberg points out in the link I posted, if one is using a multitude of frameworks, one is often going to be guaranteed to be writing a fair amount of boiler plate for exceptions even if one is not interested in many of them.