# XCTAssertThrowsError failing due to thrown error. XCTAssertThrowsError failed: throwing Invalid type in JSON write (NSObject)

Tags: swift, xctest

I have a function that creates JSON data from a dictionary, and have specified that it `throws` to propagate the error up the stack:

```swift
func createBodyDataFrom(dictionary: [String: Any]) throws -> Data {
        let bodyData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])

        return bodyData
    }
```

However when testing using an `XCTAssertThrowsError` I get a test failure, according to XCode BECAUSE the function threw an exception

```swift
func testCreateJSONFrominValidDictionaryThrows() {
        let validDictionary: [String: Any] = [
            "object": NSObject()
        ]
        XCTAssertThrowsError(try testClient.createBodyDataFrom(dictionary: validDictionary))
    }
```

The failure message from the IDE gives:

> XCTAssertThrowsError failed: throwing Invalid type in JSON write (NSObject)

This seems contradictory, but leaving the failure case untested feels incomplete. Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Let's start by running some equivalent code in Objective-C so that we understand what Cocoa does under the hood here:

```
NSDictionary* d = @{@"Howdy": [NSObject new]};
NSError* err;
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@", err);
```

If this were the sort of thing that results in an NSError, we would be able to read the value of `err` and print it to the console. But it isn't, and we can't. We never got to the NSLog statement. Instead, the program crashes unceremoniously:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSObject)'
```

```
    1   libobjc.A.dylib  0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation       0x00007fff2580cb68 -[_NSJSONWriter writeRootObject:toStream:options:error:] + 0
    3   Foundation       0x00007fff2580ff03 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 371
[and so on]
```

That is *not* an NSError. It is an NSException. They are completely different things, and basically it means our program crashes. It is not a throw-and-catch of an error; it is sudden death.

That is what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data) warned us would happen. This method, `dataWithJSONObject:options:error`, does not fail in good order if we supply an object that cannot be turned into JSON. It crashes instead:

> If `obj` will not produce valid JSON, an exception is thrown. This exception is thrown *prior to parsing* and represents a *programming* error, not an *internal* error. *You* should check whether the input will produce valid JSON *before* calling this method by using `isValidJSONObject:`.

(Italics mine.)

So the correct way to discover the issue and prevent the crash was to call `isValidJSONObject:` *first*. This method, `dataWithJSONObject:options:error`, will not catch this sort of problem and return a mere NSError; it will kill the whole program.

And that is what happened to *you*. Your call to `try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:)` did *not* `throw`. It just crashed. You can see that if you try it by itself in an actual Swift app:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        try testCreateJSONFrominValidDictionaryThrows()
    } catch {
        print("oops")
    }
}
func createBodyDataFrom(dictionary: [String: Any]) throws -> Data {
    let bodyData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
    return bodyData
}
func testCreateJSONFrominValidDictionaryThrows() throws {
    let validDictionary: [String: Any] = [
        "object": NSObject()
    ]
    try createBodyDataFrom(dictionary: validDictionary)
}
```

We run the app, and what happens? We do *not* print "oops". Instead, we get exactly the same crash as in Objective-C.

And that is what happens to *your* case as well. We never threw because we crashed instead. And the test failure reports that fact. Your `testClient` crashed out from under you (you might be able to detect this with some twiddling of the Console), and the test itself came back as a failure because we never threw an NSError.

---

The difference between Cocoa throwing an NSException and returning an NSError is crucial here. Only the latter counts for Swift as throwing an error; the former is a crash. See for example

[How can I throw an NSError from a Swift class and catch it in an Objective-C class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455883/how-can-i-throw-an-nserror-from-a-swift-class-and-catch-it-in-an-objective-c-cla/58456013#58456013)

[Avoid handling all exceptions until they've reached a global handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384781/avoid-handling-all-exceptions-until-theyve-reached-a-global-handler)

[How to catch NSUnknownKeyException in swift 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494218/how-to-catch-nsunknownkeyexception-in-swift-2-2)

Comment: Handling Errors in Swift:

In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

You call this method in a try expression and handle any errors in the catch clauses of a do statement, as described in Error Handling in The Swift Programming Language and About Imported Cocoa Error Parameters.

Comment: I don't actually know under what circumstances this method would return an NSError in good order. So I cannot account for the uninformative (perhaps incorrect) documentation on that point. I know only that the circumstances we are testing, namely a value that cannot produce valid JSON, does not return an NSError in good order; it generates an NSException instead; that is what my code (and yours) proves, and that is in fact documented in a rather elliptical way. I wouldn't set too much store by the docs anyway; I make my living by being skeptical about the docs. Run the code I gave, and see.